# Удалить дубли в Linux по маске

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, centos

Составить команду для Linux CentOS

Нужно удалить дубли с практически одинаковыми названиями, содержащими цифры в конце.

Есть:

```
Авария на Чернобыльской АЭС.ppt
Авария на Чернобыльской АЭС 345.ppt
АА Лекция 13 Ю Защита в чс ДЛЯ ЗО.ppt
АА Лекция 13 Ю Защита в чс ДЛЯ.ppt
Обозначения в автоматике 194.ppt
Барклай де Толли.ppt
```

Оставить:

```
Авария на Чернобыльской АЭС.ppt
АА Лекция 13 Ю Защита в чс ДЛЯ.ppt
Обозначения в автоматике 194.ppt
Барклай де Толли.ppt
```

**fdupes** удалить дубли не помог.

Comment: Составил команду для удаления ВСЕХ (не только дублей) файлов с цифрами на конце.

`find . -regex '\./.*[0-9-].ppt' -delete`
 
Для этого проекта не особо критично удалить пару лишних файлов, так что оставил пока так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашла на мой взгляд самое правильное решение

```
ls | sort -f | uniq -dw 10 | while read d; do echo "$d"; done
```

Команду после теста заменяем на rm и выставляем правильное количество
знаков по которым ведется отбор. У меня стоит 10 но есть резон оптимизировать
опытным путем

Comment: То, что в результате сортировки файлы с цифрами окажутся впереди почти таких же имен файлов с буквами и именно они попадут в вывод uniq я понял, а вот как отсеять тут файлы, *не являющиеся дубликатами* не понимю. Сможете объяснить?

Comment: @avp, ключ `-d` заставляет `uniq` выводить только повторяющиеся строки.

Comment: В моей строчке кода команда sort -f сортирует файлы так, что первыми из дубликатов выводятся те в которых есть цифры перед расширением. А уже команда uniq -d инвертирует вывод и выводит именно первые файлы по совпадению, именно те в которых есть цифры перед расширением. Я так поняла это и есть дубликаты оригинальных файлов которые надо удалить.